# Please help to solve characteristics equations.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

please help me to solve following characteristics equations:

> $$\frac{dx}{x+by+cty+f_{1}(t)} = \frac{dy}{-bx+y-ctx+f_{2}(t)} = \frac{dt}{kt} = \frac{d\psi}{(2-k)\psi+\frac{1}{2}c(x^2+y^2)-x\dot{f_{1}}(t)+y\dot{f_{2}}(t)}$$

where 'dot' is derivative with respect to '$t$'

Comment: Give us the context of your study and what you have tried.

Comment: I don't even know from where to start with as all variable present every ratio except third.